# vuejs .vue component debounce getting itself as input

Tags: vuejs2

Before I started to use `.vue` components I wrote a component that had the following code working successufuly

```
import { debounce } from '../utils/debounce';
Vue.component('play-list-manager', {
  ...
  methods: {
    renamePlayList: debounce((oldName, event) => {
      store.dispatch(Actions.renamePlayList(oldName, event.target.value));
      }, 500),
  },
  template: `<input
            type="text"
            v-bind:value="tag.name"
            v-on:keyup="renamePlayList(tag.name, $event)"
            placeholder="... playlist name">`
});
```

but when I switched to `.vue` components it does not work anymore

The problem is that the input of debounce it not `('some name', Event)` but it now is `(function(oldName, event), 500)`. So it's getting the input of debounce as input.

What is the correct way to add a debounce function.

Just for completion here is my debounce function

```
export function debounce(func, wait) {
    // we need to save these in the closure
    let timeout;
    let args;
    let context;
    let timestamp;

    return () => {
        // save details of latest call
        context = this;
        args = [].slice.call(arguments, 0);
        timestamp = new Date();

        // this is where the magic happens
        const later = () => {
            // how long ago was the last call
            const last = (new Date()) - timestamp;

            // if the latest call was less that the wait period ago
            // then we reset the timeout to wait for the difference
            if (last < wait) {
                timeout = setTimeout(later, wait - last);

                // or if not we can null out the timer and run the latest
            } else {
                timeout = null;
                func.apply(context, args);
            }
        };

        // we only need to set the timer now if one isn't already running
        if (!timeout) {
            timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, though I do not understand it completely

```
export function debounce(func, wait) {
    // we need to save these in the closure
    let timeout;
    let args;
    let context;
    let timestamp;

    return function() {
        // save details of latest call
        context = this;
        args = [].slice.call(arguments, 0);
        timestamp = new Date();

        // this is where the magic happens
        const later = () => {
            // how long ago was the last call
            const last = (new Date()) - timestamp;

            // if the latest call was less that the wait period ago
            // then we reset the timeout to wait for the difference
            if (last < wait) {
                timeout = setTimeout(later, wait - last);

                // or if not we can null out the timer and run the latest
            } else {
                timeout = null;
                func.apply(context, args);
            }
        };

        // we only need to set the timer now if one isn't already running
        if (!timeout) {
            timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        }
    };
}
```